# Using Firebase from Firefox and Safari extensions

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firefox-addon, firebase-authentication, safari-extension

Is it possible to use Firebase (authentication and database) from Firefox add-ons and Safari extensions? Similar to [Google Chrome Extension](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js/tree/master/auth/chromextension)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase does not support Firefox add-ons and Safari extensions currently.

You can view a full list of supported environments on [this page](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/environments_js-sdk#other_environments).

You can also submit a feature request for Firebase support of other environments such as Firefox add-ons and Safari extensions [here](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/report/features).